# Signing Messages Ethers.js

Tags: solidity, ethers.js

I want to send a request for signing a message on MetaMask.
the method i assumed should do it is the signer.SignMessage(msg) however this is returning the signature without asking for approval on MetaMask.

```
const contract = require( "../artifacts/contracts/token.sol/token.json" );
const keys = require( "../keys.json" );

const alchemyProvider = new ethers.providers.AlchemyProvider( network = "ropsten", keys.ALCHEMY_API_KEY );
const signer = new ethers.Wallet( keys.ROPSTEN_PRIVATE_KEY, alchemyProvider );
const token = new ethers.Contract( keys.TOKEN_ADDRESS, contract.abi, signer );

async function main ()
{

    msg = "Hallo Welt";
    let signature = await signer.signMessage( msg );
    console.log( signature );
}
main();
```

the console is returning the signature hash already. Should I use a different Method?

Comment: I think you are looking in the wrong place (for me this is only a script and run on your node js and not in browser) . check this example https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vhUjCLYlnMM and this https://docs.metamask.io/guide/signing-data.html

Comment: this also looks good https://medium.com/coinmonks/signing-messages-in-ethereum-5517040c2ff1  you need to take care that some of the sign method are deperacted and some are critical can be used but should not.

Answer (score 1):

The private key is hardcoded so it does not need metamask's approval even if you connect your wallet.